# Performance issues with fading effect in canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CsBCp/) code that results in a pencil with fade effect. I did it basing on [this](http://hakim.se/experiments/html5/trail/03/) example. I am now using it along with other heavy stuff (WebRTC) on a mobile website. The problem is that this code uses a timer (`setInterval(loop, 1000 / 60);`) to create the fading effect and this seems to be quite heavy.

Is there another (lighter) way to have a pencil with fade effect in HTML5/Canvas?

Comment: Depends what is running in that loop.

Comment: Everything is on the jsfiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've already done a performant step by moving the frame drawing to a timed loop instead of drawing in a move-handler.

Now you can allow your loop to be more performant by using requestAnimationFrame (RAF) instead of setInterval.

RAF is preferred because is more resource friendly:

- RAF executes when resources are available and delays when resources are scarce.
- If RAF is executing in a browser tab and focus switches to another tab, RAF suspends.
- If multiple loops are executing RAF, RAF will group and buffer browser changes.

You can even wrap RAF inside a setTimeout if you need more uniform timing of your loops.

Since setTimeout is asynchronous, you're not consuming the UI thread while it's counting down.

```
var fps = 30;
function animate() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        // update frame info here

        // draw the new frame here

    }, 1000 / fps);
}
```

Here is a very good post on why using RAF is preferable from a performance standpoint:

http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/

Comment: Nice! I tried to improve performance by cancelling the timer when not drawing anything and decreasing the framerate from 60 fps to 30 as in your answer and compared what I got with your suggestion. Both seem to be a way better then what I had in my question. Also, both don't break the real-time feeling when only accessing the cam with WebRTC, however, starting a video-conference makes everything terrible... I guess I will have to buy a better phone...